# CSS 80's TRON Grid

Tags: css, grid, background-image, css-transforms, linear-gradients

I'm wanting to build an "80's TRON Grid" effect with CSS but I'm running into a few issues with getting it where I want it.

Stuff like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=80s%20tron%20grid&num=50&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7uq7Ky-XeAhUQvKwKHcOLCjwQ_AUIDigB&biw=1536&bih=794&dpr=1.25).

[image]

**My Requirements:**

- Fade 1 side to transparent
- Package it up into a nice `.class` to put on any `<element>` and it just work

---

I've made 2 attempts at this w/ 2 different techniques.

**80's Grid #1 (pseudo selectors)** 
https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/MPQWBE 
Although this works perfectly, it's not ideal to put 10 `<div>`'s in my html every time I want the effect.

```css
body { background: black; }

.grid-container { 
 position: absolute; width: 200%; height: 100vh; bottom: 0; left: -50%; overflow: hidden; 
 transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(40deg) scale(1) translateZ(0);
 transform-origin: bottom;
 padding: 1px; 
 -webkit-background-clip: content-box; 
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 outline: 1px solid transparent; 
 will-change: transform; 
}

.grid-line { height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; }


.grid-line:before,
.grid-line:after  { content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; }
.grid-line:before { height: 5px; width: 100%; background: blue; }
.grid-line:after  { height: 100%; width: 5px; background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, blue); }

.grid-line:nth-child(1):before  { top: 0%;  opacity: 0; }
.grid-line:nth-child(2):before  { top: 10%; opacity: 0; }
.grid-line:nth-child(3):before  { top: 20%; opacity: .3; }
.grid-line:nth-child(4):before  { top: 30%; opacity: .4; }
.grid-line:nth-child(5):before  { top: 40%; opacity: .5; }
.grid-line:nth-child(6):before  { top: 50%; opacity: .6; }
.grid-line:nth-child(7):before  { top: 60%; opacity: .7; }
.grid-line:nth-child(8):before  { top: 70%; opacity: .8; }
.grid-line:nth-child(9):before  { top: 80%; opacity: .9; }
.grid-line:nth-child(10):before { top: 90%; opacity: 1; }
.grid-line:nth-child(11):before { top: calc(100% - 3px); }


.grid-line:nth-child(1):after  { left: 0%;  }
.grid-line:nth-child(2):after  { left: 10%; }
.grid-line:nth-child(3):after  { left: 20%; }
.grid-line:nth-child(4):after  { left: 30%; }
.grid-line:nth-child(5):after  { left: 40%; }
.grid-line:nth-child(6):after  { left: 50%; }
.grid-line:nth-child(7):after  { left: 60%; }
.grid-line:nth-child(8):after  { left: 70%; }
.grid-line:nth-child(9):after  { left: 80%; }
.grid-line:nth-child(10):after { left: 90%; }
.grid-line:nth-child(11):after { left: calc(100% - 3px); }
```

```html
<section class="grid-container">
 <div class="grid-line"></div>
 <div class="grid-line"></div>
 <div class="grid-line"></div>
 <div class="grid-line"></div>
 <div class="grid-line"></div> 
 <div class="grid-line"></div>
 <div class="grid-line"></div>
 <div class="grid-line"></div>
 <div class="grid-line"></div>
 <div class="grid-line"></div>
 <div class="grid-line"></div>
</section>
```

**80's Grid #2 (linear-gradient)** 
https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/OaQNPe 
This technique is ideal because it allows me to use 1 `.class` on 1 `<element>`, but I'm not sure how to make it fade out.

```css
body { background: black; }

.grid-container { width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; }

.grid-container:after { 
  
 transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(40deg) scale(2,1) translateZ(0);
  content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 100vh;
  padding: 1px; 
  -webkit-background-clip: content-box; 
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  will-change: transform; 
}

.grid-container:after {
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(to right, blue 1px, transparent 0), 
  linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 3px, transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-container">
</section>
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `mask-image` with an alpha gradient to achieve the effect you're looking for.

```
.grid-container:after { 
   -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 90%, left top, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
   mask-image: gradient(linear, left 90%, left top, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
}
```

Take a look here: https://codepen.io/JoahG/pen/QJQdJB

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!