# Line with more glow in the middle than start and end

Tags: css

I was looking at some 80's retro design, and came across some glowy stuff, including this one:

[image]

Can this be achieved with CSS ? I mean, create a line and do some box shadow. But I have to have more glow in the middle, and less in the sides, and I am not sure how this can be accomplished in just CSS ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://codepen.io/aderaaij/pen/amqoVJ

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416334/css-80s-tron-grid

Comment: Maybe it was unclear. I am not interested in the grid, I am more interested in the center "line" where there is more glow in the middle than in the sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
:root {
    --clr-inner: #fed9ff;
    --clr-outer: #c727c9;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.box .line-outer {
    background: var(--clr-outer);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 10px var(--clr-outer);
    filter: blur(1px);
    height: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.box .line-outer .line-inner {
    background: var(--clr-inner);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 15px var(--clr-inner);
    filter: blur(1px);
    height: 4px;
    left: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="line-outer">
        <div class="line-inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a radial gradient ?
(you can adjust parameters using : https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/gradient/)

```css
#demo {
background: #FFFFFF;
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, #FFFFFF 0%, #A42799 64%, #000000 100%);
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, #FFFFFF 0%, #A42799 64%, #000000 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #FFFFFF 0%, #A42799 64%, #000000 100%);
height:50px;
width:100%
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```